# Is there a flag hook (flag module) which is called when a flagged node is saved?

Tags: flags

I am using the [flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) to flag content.

Say user A flags a node. When user B updates the node, I want to send a mail to the user A (who flagged the node - I know I can use the Notifications and Messaging module but I want to send a notification in another way).

Is there an hook called when a flagged node is saved? So I can tap in on that hook and then retrieve a list of all users who flagged the node?

Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Is there an hook called when a flagged node is saved ?
> ```

- No

However, you can use [`hook_node_update`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) to trigger on a regular node save and check users who have flagged the current node ID.

You can also do most of the work without any coding using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and obviously, [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

Answer (score 2):

I am using D6 and I use and implementation for the hook_nodeapi and hook_comment.

I am using a flag named follow. See the code below, maybe it can be of any help for someone.

This code returns a list of uids who have flagged the node which has changed (or has a new comment attached to it).

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_nodeapi().
 */
function MYMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {

  switch ($op) {
    case 'update':     
  // check if this node is flagged
  $flag_name = 'follow';
  $flag = flag_get_flag($flag_name);

  if($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid)) {
     $list_uid = flag_get_content_flags(node, $node->nid, $flag_name, FALSE);
     $flags_by_uids = array();
     foreach($list_uid as $flags_by_uid)
     {
       $flags_by_uids[] = array($flags_by_uid->uid);
     }
  }
  break;
}
}
/**
 * Implementation of hook_comment().
 */
function MYMODULE_comment(&$a1, $op) {

  switch ($op) {
    case 'publish':
  // check if this node is flagged
  $flag_name = 'follow';
  $flag = flag_get_flag($flag_name);

  if($flag && $flag->is_flagged($a1[nid])) {
     $list_uid = flag_get_content_flags(node, $a1[nid], $flag_name, FALSE);
     $flags_by_uids = array();
     foreach($list_uid as $flags_by_uid)
     {
       $flags_by_uids[] = array($flags_by_uid->uid);
     }
  }
  break;
}
}
```

Comment: this really is helpful - at least for my own use. Thanks Paul!